# NSUserNotificationCenter defaultNotificationcenter returns nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications

I feel like I am going insane here.

I'm making a little command-line tool to let me know when a Twitch channel I like goes live. So far, everything works. There's only one, small issue: `[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter]` is consistently returning `nil`, no matter where I call it in the program. This is a bit of a problem, since I need to be able to send notifications.

After a solid hour of googling, I can't figure out what's going on. Something like `[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] setDelegate:myDelegate]` doesn't crash, but I'm pretty sure that's because you can send messages to `nil` in Obj-C. Similarly, I can do something like `[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultNotificationCenter] deliverNotification: mynote]`, but nothing is displayed onscreen (and this is with the delegate for `[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter]` set to return `YES` for the `userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center shouldPresentNotification:(NSUserNotification *)`method.)

Additionally, all notifications presented via `deliverNotification` do not have their `delivered` property set to YES.

The only thing I can think of is that the usage of `NSUserNotificationCenter` only works if you're running an `NSApplication`, but I cannot find that documented anywhere. I'm running a simple command-line tool, which is pretty much a `main` function, an `@autoreleasepool`, and some method calls.

Is there anything obvious that can cause `[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter]` to return nil?

Comment: have you put an NSLog somewhere to check that `[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter]` is nil? or how can you say that?

Comment: Tried it with both NSLog notifications and a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

> The only thing I can think of is that the usage of NSUserNotificationCenter only works if you're running an NSApplication, but I cannot find that documented anywhere.

I don't think it would be easy to find it explicitly documented somewhere, but if your app is a simple command line tool, i.e., it is not using a `NSRunLoop`, I doubt that features like notifications can work at all. They intrinsically require your program to have a run loop that sits there waiting for events (e.g., a notification coming in, a click, a touch) and dispatching them to whomever should handle them.

You might try starting and `NSRunLoop` from you main function, but it would cease to be a simple command-line tool, I guess.

Comment: Started an NSRunLoop on the main function. Still returns nil, for some reason.

Comment: I have the same problem and I have posted some code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341643